# How to Access a Private Variable?

Tags: c++, class, private

This question isn't meant to sound as blatantly insulting as it probably is right now.

This is a homework assignment, and the spec sheet is scarce and poorly designed to say the least. We have a function:

```
double refuel( int liter, GasStation *gs )
{
    // TODO: Access private variable MaxFuel of gs and decrement.
}
```

Sound simple enough? It should be, but the class GasStation comes with no function that accesses the private variable MaxFuel. So how can I access it anyway using the function refuel?

I'm not considering creating a function `setFuel( int liter )` because the teacher always complains rather energetically if I change his specification. So... I guess I have to do some sort of hack around it, but I'm not sure how to go about this without explicitely changing the only function in GasStation and giving it a parameter so that I can call it here.

Any hints perhaps?

Comment: Private variables are designed *not* to be accessed. What kind of homework is this!

Comment: Let me get this straight. In a nutshell, your assignment is, given a concrete class which you can't change, to specifically access and modify a private member, which has no accessors, from outside the class definition?

Comment: Wow.  Passing a naked class pointer into a function to access a private var.  Ick.  Is there any sort of get() method for the MaxFuel value you are looking at or perhaps there's a enum or const you're supposed to grab?  If this was given to multiple students, I would think that this problem would have come up by now.

Comment: Remember kids: Only friends can touch your privates.

Comment: This instructor needs to be keel-hauled.

Comment: Well, read Herb Sutter's take on it @ http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm; especially the 'Language Lawyer Solution' :-)

Comment: @ zildjohn01: yes
@ Dorgan: Nope, the entire specs, as said, are extremely scarce. No enum, no inheritance, no friend functions. 
@ Abhay: Thanks for the link!

Comment: @SoulBeaver: so according to the Sutter article that Abhay pointed to, the key (to a standard's compliant solution anyway) is whether the `GasStation` class has a member template that can be specialized. otherwise it looks lke you're stuck with one of the 'less than legal' hacks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I transform an object and access the private data members in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513140/can-i-transform-an-object-and-access-the-private-data-members-in-c)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Now that sounds like a real lousy homework assignment.*

Anyway, I can think of three ways to access private data:

1. through public member functions
2. by a `friend` of the class
3. cheating:

   ```
   #define private public 
   #include "the_class.h"
   #undef private
   ```

The first two are legal, but require you to change the class. The last is "non-intrusive" (for some definition of "non-intrusive", anyway), but is definitely illegal (although I have yet to see a compiler were it wouldn't work).

Comment: #3 is dirty!  I'd not seen that before :)

Comment: Of course, there's always type-punning.  This is also "cheating" and undefined, of course.

Comment: @Michael You could have seen it [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002101/how-can-i-violate-encapsulation-property/3004223#3004223) ;-)

Comment: +1. 
3) actually helped me to debug OpenCV without rebuilding the library.

Answer (score 3):

Declare `refuel(..)` as a friend function. Otherwise, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

Compile and run a test program.  Run it in a debugger and examine the memory layout of GasStation.  calculate the exact distance in bytes what the distance from the start of a GasStation to the int you need to set is (note if it's the first thing and there's no virtual functions then that distance is guaranteed to be 0 so you can omit the first few steps).

Use this value to increment the pointer to the position within the object where you need to set the data as Kirill shows.  However, just to be an ass--your teacher deserves it--do not use any symbolic language here...use the value of the distance directly like so:

```
*reinterpret_cast<int*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(gs)+42);
```

or whatever 42 should be to get to the right place.

If you really want to be an ass, put a fake variable in your function.  Compile and run the program and then find the distance on the stack between this fake variable and the location of the GasStation pointer data.  Then do this:

```
*reinterpret_cast<int*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(*reinterpret_cast<char**>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&my_var)-666)) + 42) = new_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a suitably terrible solution for your teacher's terrible assignment.

```
#define private public
#include "GasStation.h"
#undef private
```

Comment: Please don't encourage him! LOL A friend is a better option!

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the point of a `GasStation` is to offer `GasStation::pump(Car&)`. This will decrement `private: unsigned int MaxFuel` for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is dirty, but you can do:

```
#define private public
#include "GasStation.h" // Or whatever the name is
```

Now the compiler thinks everything in that header is public. Joy!

Comment: Is a compiler error or just a check within one of the MS headers?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to add public member function to `GasStation`.

Something less safe is to make `refuel` a friend function.

Absolutely not safe option is available if you know offset of member `MaxFuel` in that class. Then you could change it as follows (NEVER DO THIS IN PRODUCTION CODE):

```
int* max_fuel = reinterpret_cast<int*>( reinterpret_cast<char*>(gs)+MaxFuel_OFFSET );
*max_fuel = new_value;
```

Comment: Did you not mean `*max_fuel = new_value;` ?